# How to automate book button in IRCTC while booking a train in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

How to automate "book" button in IRCTC while booking a train in selenium webdriver. I need Java code???
is this code is correct?

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("//*[@id='j_idt335_body']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Did you try it?  Trying your code will tell you if it is correct.  If you have a problem you can edit your question to present the problem for someone to explain and offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this-

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Book Now"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Store webelements in list.

   ```
   @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//a[text()='Book Now']")
       List<WebElement> bookTBtn;
   ```
2. Get one by one webElement and check if text is equal to "Book now".

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<bookTBtn.size();i++){
           WebElement bookTiketBtn=bookTBtn.get(i);
           String text=bookTiketBtn.getText();
           System.out.println(text);
           if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Book Now")){
               bookTiketBtn.click();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Book Now")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. it uses various CSS selectors that navigate the DOM structure (especially the `nth-child` selector):

```
driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector(
    "#c1 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(2)"
  )
).click();
```